# Because you like puzzles, but you see clearly... or do you?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, word-property

> $$\rm md\to thk\to in.$$

Because thoughts are grey, but not sad.

> $$\rm we\to gt \to if.$$

Because your best mate deserves a present, but you are not friends.

> $$\rm cy\to se\to \:?$$

Because the town is large, but not the population.

---

***What word is the question mark?***

Comment: ***This is not my intended anagram puzzle — I did not save my progress, and it all got deleted. Here is to make up for that.***

Comment: nice puzzle, too bad the anagram puzzle got lost though, i love those..

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I know... :\

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is

> it

Because

> in each case, the last word can be placed inside the other two to form words relevant to the clues

md→thk→in.
Because thoughts are grey, but not sad.

> m**in**d th**in**k

we→gt→if.
Because your best mate deserves a present, but you are not friends.

> w**if**e, g**if**t

cy→se→?

> c**it**y, s**it**e

Comment: I seem to have attracted the attention of someone with an IQ of 3000. I mean, how did you get the answer *that* quickly? Explain the "because..." lines, though :P

Comment: Haha! Just happened to see it at the right time. The first one just jumped out at me for some reason, and the rest fell into place then. Added more detail on the answers

Comment: Well, I did not expect that, but that is a good thing. I sort of get a taste of what this site has to offer.... heheh (this comment is a hint).

Comment: +1 After seeing this answer, I can't seem to thk->in of anythg->in else

Comment: @user477343, is this the correct answer or should we keep searching?

Comment: @user477343 If it's the correct answer, make sure to mark it with the green checkmark.

Comment: @El-Guest yes this is the correct answer. Sorry I didn't accept it; I had to go to bed. (I'm Australian. If you don't believe me, you can check what time it is now in Australia and subtract $7$ hours). But now I'm awake, so...

Comment: @SolomonUcko look at my comment above :P

Comment: ....congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @user477343 I see, sorry.

Comment: @SolomonUcko no, don't be sorry! Hahah, you did nothing wrong. It was just a misunderstanding, that's all :)

Comment: I think we're quite used to recongizing words by their fisrt and last letter which is why you may not have even noticed the intetnional typos in this sentence.
"city" is also the first thing that came to my mind when I saw the question. Even though it's ostensibly the same puzzle and the same "search space", I think if you were to come up with a puzzle which reverses the schema so that the outside letters have to match (and be guessed at the end) it would be significantly more difficult.

Comment: @user477343 no worries buddy!

Comment: @dspyz I did not know that... is that true? You made a typo in the word "first", but I knew that... by looking at the first and last letters? That's pretty cool, and that also means you can raed tihs vrey stencene eevn wehn wrdos rmaein srbmcaeld eecxpt for tiehr lsat frsit and ltteres?

Comment: I found a stackexchange question referring to the same thing I probably saw:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8628/is-it-true-that-only-the-positions-of-the-first-and-last-letter-in-a-word-matter

Comment: Also I had a typo in "recognizing" and "intentional"